# Draw a text inside MTKView

Tags: swift, metal, mtkview

I started to work on a project that the old colleges used metal to draw a graph. I am looking for a fast solution to add a label inside this `MTKView`.

Here is what I have so far:

```
for coordinate in coordinates {
    let circleVertice = CircleVertex(x: coordinate, y: 200, radius: 20)
    rrIntervals += circleVertice.toVertices(perimeterPoints: perimeterPoints)
}
```

As you can see, I have the coordinate, it's the coordinate of the label that moves with graph until it goes out of the screen.
For example, I want to add a label with string of `"Test"` here, what is the best and fastest way to add this label in this MTKView with this coordinate. This code inside of a subclass of `MTKView` class.

Comment: Peter, if you are looking for a fast way to draw text, why not mix SpriteKit with Metal?

Comment: @0xBFE1A8 if I can see one example, it could help me a lot